# How to set a Negative Value to an Input box in php

Tags: php, javascript

```
<input type="number" class="addme" value="'.$_REQUEST['pbill'].'" name="amount" min="0" required="required" placeholder="Enter amount of Pending Bills" title="Enter amount of Pending Bills" pattern="[0-9]{1,}" />
```

How do I ensure that the value to be input in the above will be a negative value?

Comment: this is an excerpt from a form that will hold data which should be deducted from the total, that is why i need it in form of a negative value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after wide consultations i have come to the conclusion that this is the most viable answer...thanks to all that helped in the query
 $_REQUEST['amount'] = -$_REQUEST['amount'];

Answer (score 1):

check the posted value, like

```
 $amount = $_POST['amount'];

 if($amount > 0) {
      //echo 'positive';
      $req_amt = (0 - $amount);
 } else {
      echo 'negative or 0';
 }
```

Comment: sir what you have done above is validation, i on the other hand want to turn any data input into a negative value

Comment: How are you getting values in the amount input field, If you need always negative means simply subtract the amount from 0.  example 0-10 will give -10

Comment: i'm using $_GET to post into the database, so the calculation would have to be done beforehand, let me try it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing sure about using pattern. You should check it out server side. But if You would like to use pattern to check this out, the pattern should be `\-[0-9]+`

As for PHP:

You simply check the value before inserting it to database:

```
if($_REQUEST['amount'] >= 0){ // $_REQUEST is generally for $_GET and $_POST
    echo "Incorrect amount given. Please try again.";
    die();
}
```

Comment: its not about the pattern i'm worried about, i want to be able to input data that will be inserted into the database in negative form.

Comment: so there is no way i can change the value before it gets to the database? for example if i were to input 2, it would be saved as -2 in the database

Comment: `if($_REQUEST['amount'] >= 0) $_REQUEST['amount'] = -$_REQUEST['amount'];`

Comment: this would do excellently if the problem was when posting into the db, but there is a calculation that needs to be done before the final figure can be inserted into the database using javascript, that's where my issue is